# Protected Client Server communication advice

Tags: tls

I am hoping for a better understanding about SSL/TLS by setting up two devices, running two different applications, allowing communications to go over SSL/TLS.

With OpenSSL I have created a **certificate** and **key** which I installed on both, the server and the client.
On the client side, I can also choose from three cipher suites (on the server I don't have that option to choose from).

- TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

I use Wireshark to see what is going on during the communication that always fails, no matter what  I select from above.
I see a normal TCP communication: SYN, SYN ACK, ACK and then a FIN from the client.
It is very obvious, I am doing something wrong, but honestly no clue what to do.
It seems that it doesn't even get to the point of using the SSL protocol.

Can anyone please clarify things for me what  Iam doing wrong and hand me a possible solution?
This requires more professional security skills.
Thanks in advance !
John

P.S.: I want to use self-signed certificates since it is only used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you see *only* the ACK, SYN+ACK, ACK and FIN packets, then you are seeing the shell of a TCP connection, but no data. If the FIN is from the client, then *the client* apparently decides that it has nothing to say. So this points at a configuration issue on the client: when the client should begin the SSL/TLS conversation (by sending the `ClientHello` message), it just gives up. In any case, at that point, the role of the server is to wait for the `ClientHello`, so its own SSL-level configuration has not been exercised yet.

---

Now some general comments:

- In SSL/TLS, the server should have a private/public key pair, the public key being wrapped in a *certificate*. The client *may* also have a private/public key pair -- but not the same one ! The whole point of [asymmetric cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) is to avoid having to share private elements between different entities. In fact, you should strive *never* to let private keys travel between systems: the more a key journeys, the more exposed it gets, thus the less private it becomes.
- *Cipher suites* select the set of cryptographic algorithms which will be used. In the three suites you talk, RSA will be used for the initial key exchange (so the server's public key should be of type RSA), and SHA-1 for integrity protection. The symmetric encryption will use, respectively, nothing at all, 3DES, or AES. If unsure, use AES. If you are thinking about using the "NULL" encryption, then think again.
- If you want to use SSL/TLS, and, even more, if you want to debug some SSL-related issues and have begun launching Wireshark (that's a good thing), then you will need to understand how SSL works. You could do worse than reading [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/20847#20847) for some explanations on that.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. It seems that the client is indeed not sending out a ClientHello message. It just finalizes the TCP three-way handshake and that's it. Is it possible that the certificates are "wrong/bad" causing the Client to stop the communication for that possible reason?

Comment: We can certainly imagine that anything in the client configuration which does not please the client could induce it to just give up. What is certain, though, is that it is not a problem of _server_ configuration, since at that time the server has not said anything yet.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I checked the server log and now it says: "DUL secure tranport layer: unspecified TLS error". This tells me that the server did try something?

Comment: If the TCP three-way handshake was done, then the server actually expects incoming connection. If a client connects, and then the client drops the connection instead of sending the `ClientHello`, it is understandable that the server logs something which should be "the client closed the connection before sending his `ClientHello`" but for many implementations, the log entry will probably be more cryptic and say something like, indeed, "unspecified error". This does not tell you more than you already knew.

Comment: makes sense. I will do some more research and if I have something to report, I'll let you know. It may be helpful for someone else as well, struggling with the same problem as I have.